# How can InfluxDB be used as Spark Source

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, influxdb

How can an InfluxDB database (which has streaming data coming in) be used as Source for Spark Streaming ?
Also, Is it possible to use InfluxDB instead of SparkSQL for performing computations on datasets ?

Comment: Did you find a way for achieving this?